# install psycopg2 on any machine

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

so I have an app I'm writing in Postgres - but I want someone to be able to clone the repo and run a simple install script to set it up - I also want to be able to just pop it up in a container or on an amazon box using the same script.

It does a pip install of a bunch of things, and it's all fine except for psycopg2 - because you can't install it without having a pg_config in the path.

Anyone got any ideas how to make a script that, on any machine with python on it - will achieve a working version of psycopg2?    I do *not* want to be installing a Postgres instance on every box, and even if I did - the installs seem to be different on different machines - and I want this to run on windows, Mac, linux or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/   ?

Comment: yep - it still seems to want pg_config available in the path?